# closing youtube player embedded in a modal window

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, modal-dialog

I am using embeded youtube videos on a webpage.
The youtube video player is embedded in an iframe in a modal window. When I close the modal window (display=none) the video is still playing (it is not visible but I can still hear the audio).

Is there a command that I can use in my function closeModal() that would close the video?
Ideally I would like to be able to close ANY video that is playing and avoid using the video-id in the close-video command because there are more than one videos on my page.

many thanks,
Chris

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/GIc3aFVv6-E/0.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/MQnr9z1a0uI/0.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/nsr9HCOgQe0/0.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GIc3aFVv6-E?color=white" width="100%" height="auto"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MQnr9z1a0uI?color=white" width="100%" height="auto"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nsr9HCOgQe0?color=white" width="100%" height="auto"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </div>    

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>



  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: clear src and assign again

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample, You can write by this way. Thanks.

Add src by click

```
var $if = $('.videoIframe');
var src = $if.attr("src");
$if.attr("src", 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/LGaHX8F8f7k?loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showsearch=0&amp;version=3&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;fs=1?v=xPe4NbWQzkM&rel=0');
});
```

And remove src when modal is closed

```
var $if = $('.videoIframe');
 var src = $if.attr("src");
 $if.attr("src", '');
 //$if.attr("src", src);
```